# Usage unit in Powertop

Tags: command-line, powertop

When I use the `powertop` utility, the Usage column values are measured in ms/s or us/s.

I'd assume the second s is second but what is the first s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The units are *milliseconds/second* or *microseconds/second*, meaning how much time within a second the task has been using the device.